# datetimepicker - duplicate display when select and get data

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using datetime picker in Yii2

```
  DateTimePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'dp_1',
                    'options' => [ 'id' => 'time_picker'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                    ]
                ])
```

and get value like this:

```
var date = $("#time_picker").datetimepicker('getDate').getTime()/1000;
```

but when I select it display duplicate :

[image]

I have no idea about this ,please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var date = $("#time_picker").datetimepicker('getDate').getTime()/1000;
```

Use

```
var date = $("#time_picker").val();
```

Because, First time you used `DateTimePicker`. It's Ok. While getting the value again for `DateTimePicker`, You are again initializing it `$("#time_picker").datetimepicker..`.

So, My opinion is to use `var date = $("#time_picker").val();` and do all calculations after getting `date` value.

Comment: Thanks you . My bug is fixed